# rails 4 template missing error in render in ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following ajax function

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/sub_categories/sub_cat',
    data: 'sub_cat=45',
    success: function() {
        alert('success');
    }
})
```

Here is my controller

```
require 'json'
class SubCategoriesController < ApplicationController
      def show
      end
      def sub_cat
          @sub_categories = SubCategory.where(category_id: params[:cat_id])
          html = render_to_string 'sub_categories/sub_cat'
          response_html true,html
      end
end
```

My application controller

```
def response_html status,html
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json {render json: { 
          status: status, 
          html: html,
        }
      }
      format.html
      end
  end
```

I have json file in `sub_categories/sub_cat.json.erb`

When I run getting error as

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate at /sub_categories/sub_cat.json
Missing template sub_categories/show, application/show with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:json], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
  * "/home/editmehere/Documents/site/name/app/views"
```

My `route.rb` has

```
resources :sub_categories do
    get 'sub_cat', on: :collection
  end
```

Why I am getting error like this and how can I solve it. Can anyone help me to solve it.

Comment: please show your `sub_cat.json.erb`. Try remove `erb` exenstion to see what happen.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're trying to keep your application dry, but why don't you just use this in your `SubCategoriesController`:

```
class SubCategoriesController < ApplicationController
    def sub_cat
      @sub_categories = SubCategory.where(category_id: params[:cat_id])
      respond_to do |format| 
         format.json
         format.html
      end
    end
end
```

This will allow you to call `sub_cat.json.erb` without having to pass the `status` var, or pre-render the HTML. This is just convention, so apologies if it's not what you need. I see a lot of people on here overcomplicate things, when simplicity would work much better

---

**Ajax**

Also, I believe you've got a problem with your ajax `data` var:

```
data: 'sub_cat=45',
```

should be

```
data: {sub_cat: "45"},
```